# Viewing the final state of an Object

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, inheritance

As a beginner I was writing a code which asks the burger buyer what they want in their burger. I did this by creating a burger object and modify its attributes by the user using a switch case method. Most of the attributes were Boolean variables. At the end of the order, what I want to do is to display all the attributes of the burger. i.e "Your burger that consists of "A" meat, "c" bread, carrots, pickles, tomatoes are ready for order." But I could not think of a practical way of displaying such a result.

I dont think I need to show the some-what awful looking code but here it is. I am open to any criticism.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("What type of burger do you want? \n1)Basic\n2)Special 1 (Healthy) \n3)Special 2 (Deluxe)");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = scanner.nextInt();

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            BasicBurger basicBurger = new BasicBurger();
            basicBurger.afterChoice();
            break;
        case 2:
            SpecialBurger1 specialBurger1 = new SpecialBurger1();
            specialBurger1.afterChoice2();
            break;
        case 3:
            SpecialBurger2 specialBurger2 = new SpecialBurger2();
            specialBurger2.afterChoice3();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            break;
    }
}
}
```

BasicBurger Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BasicBurger {
private char breadRollType;
private char meatType;
private boolean lettuce;
private boolean tomato;
private boolean carrot;
private boolean ketchup;
private double price;


public void afterChoice() {
    setPrice(5);

    System.out.println("Meat Type? (Available types = A, B, C)");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char choice = scanner.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    switch (choice) {
        case 'A':
            setMeatType('A');
            increasePrice(1);
            break;
        case 'B':
            setMeatType('B');
            increasePrice(1);
            break;
        case 'C':
            setMeatType('C');
            increasePrice(1);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("You have selected " + getMeatType() + " type of meat.\n*********");

    System.out.println("Bread Roll Type? (Available types = A, B, C)");
    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    char choice2 = scanner2.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    switch (choice2) {
        case 'A':
            setBreadRollType('A');
            break;
        case 'B':
            setBreadRollType('B');
            break;
        case 'C':
            setBreadRollType('C');
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("You have selected " + getBreadRollType() + " type of bread roll.\n*********");

    System.out.println("Tomatoes?\n1)Yes 2)No");
    Scanner scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice3 = scanner3.nextInt();

    switch (choice3) {
        case 1:
            setTomato(true);
            System.out.println("You have chosen to have tomatoes in your burger.\n*********");
            increasePrice(0.5);
            break;
        case 2:
            setTomato(false);
            System.out.println("You have chosen not to have tomatoes in your burger. \n*********");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Current price is " + getPrice() + " $\n*********");


    System.out.println("Lettuce?\n1)Yes 2)No");
    Scanner scanner4 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice4 = scanner4.nextInt();

    switch (choice4) {
        case 1:
            setLettuce(true);
            System.out.println("You have chosen to have lettuce in your burger.\n*********");
            increasePrice(1);
            break;
        case 2:
            setLettuce(false);
            System.out.println("You have chosen not to have lettuce in your burger. \n*********");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Current price is " + getPrice() + " $\n*********");


    System.out.println("Carrots?\n1)Yes 2)No");
    Scanner scanner5 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice5 = scanner5.nextInt();

    switch (choice5) {
        case 1:
            setCarrot(true);
            System.out.println("You have chosen to have carrots in your burger.\n*********");
            increasePrice(0.5);
            break;
        case 2:
            setCarrot(false);
            System.out.println("You have chosen not to have carrots in your burger. \n*********");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Current price is " + getPrice() + " $\n*********");


    System.out.println("Ketchup?\n1)Yes 2)No");
    Scanner scanner6 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice6 = scanner6.nextInt();

    switch (choice6) {
        case 1:
            setKetchup(true);
            System.out.println("You have chosen to have ketchup in your burger.\n*********");
            increasePrice(1);
            break;
        case 2:
            setKetchup(false);
            System.out.println("You have chosen not to have ketchup in your burger. \n*********");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Your order is sent.");
    System.out.println("Total price is " + getPrice() + " $\n*********");

}


public void increasePrice(double amount) {
    setPrice(getPrice() + amount);
}


public void setBreadRollType(char breadRollType) {
    this.breadRollType = breadRollType;
}

public void setMeatType(char meatType) {
    this.meatType = meatType;
}

public void setLettuce(boolean lettuce) {
    this.lettuce = lettuce;
}

public void setTomato(boolean tomato) {
    this.tomato = tomato;
}

public void setCarrot(boolean carrot) {
    this.carrot = carrot;
}

public void setKetchup(boolean ketchup) {
    this.ketchup = ketchup;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public char getBreadRollType() {
    return breadRollType;
}

public char getMeatType() {
    return meatType;
}

public boolean isLettuce() {
    return lettuce;
}

public boolean isTomato() {
    return tomato;
}

public boolean isCarrot() {
    return carrot;
}

public boolean isKetchup() {
    return ketchup;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
}
```

Special Burger 1 class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SpecialBurger1 extends BasicBurger {
private boolean pickles;
private boolean cucumber;

public void afterChoice2(){
    setPrice(6);

    setBreadRollType('B');

    System.out.println("Meat Type? (Available types = A, B, C)");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char choice = scanner.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    switch(choice){
        case 'A':
            setMeatType('A');
            break;
        case 'B':
            setMeatType('B');
            break;
        case 'C':
            setMeatType('C');
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("You have selected " + getMeatType() + " type of meat.\n*********" );

    System.out.println("Pickles?\n1)Yes 2)No");
    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice2 = scanner2.nextInt();

    switch(choice2){
        case 1:
            setPickles(true);
            System.out.println("You have chosen to have pickles in your burger\n*********");
            increasePrice(0.5);
            break;
        case 2:
            setPickles(false);
            System.out.println("You have chosen not to have pickles in your burger\n*********");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Current price is " + getPrice() + " $\n*********");


    System.out.println("Tomatoes?\n1)Yes 2)No");
    Scanner scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice3 = scanner3.nextInt();

    switch (choice3){
        case 1:
            setTomato(true);
            System.out.println("You have chosen to have tomatoes in your burger.\n*********");
            increasePrice(0.5);
            break;
        case 2:
            setTomato(false);
            System.out.println("You have chosen not to have tomatoes in your burger. \n*********");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Current price is " + getPrice() + " $\n*********");



    System.out.println("Lettuce?\n1)Yes 2)No");
    Scanner scanner4 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice4 = scanner4.nextInt();

    switch (choice4){
        case 1:
            setLettuce(true);
            System.out.println("You have chosen to have lettuce in your burger.\n*********");
            increasePrice(1);
            break;
        case 2:
            setLettuce(false);
            System.out.println("You have chosen not to have lettuce in your burger. \n*********");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Current price is " + getPrice() + " $\n*********");



    System.out.println("Carrots?\n1)Yes 2)No");
    Scanner scanner5 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice5 = scanner5.nextInt();

    switch (choice5) {
        case 1:
            setCarrot(true);
            System.out.println("You have chosen to have carrots in your burger.\n*********");
            increasePrice(0.5);
            break;
        case 2:
            setCarrot(false);
            System.out.println("You have chosen not to have carrots in your burger. \n*********");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Current price is " + getPrice() + " $\n*********");



    System.out.println("Ketchup?\n1)Yes 2)No");
    Scanner scanner6 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice6 = scanner6.nextInt();

    switch (choice6) {
        case 1:
            setKetchup(true);
            System.out.println("You have chosen to have ketchup in your burger.\n*********");
            increasePrice(1);
            break;
        case 2:
            setKetchup(false);
            System.out.println("You have chosen not to have ketchup in your burger. \n*********");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Current price is " + getPrice() + " $\n*********");


    System.out.println("Cucumber?\n1)Yes 2)No");
    Scanner scanner7 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice7 = scanner7.nextInt();

    switch (choice7) {
        case 1:
            setCucumber(true);
            System.out.println("You have chosen to have cucumber in your burger.\n*********");
            increasePrice(1);
            break;
        case 2:
            setCucumber(false);
            System.out.println("You have chosen not to have cucumber in your burger. \n*********");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Your order is sent.");
    System.out.println("Total price is " + getPrice() + " $\n*********");



}




public boolean isPickles() {
    return pickles;
}

public boolean isCucumber() {
    return cucumber;
}

public void setPickles(boolean pickles) {
    this.pickles = pickles;
}

public void setCucumber(boolean cucumber) {
    this.cucumber = cucumber;
}
}
```

Special Burger 2 class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SpecialBurger2 extends BasicBurger {
private boolean chips;
private boolean drinks;


public void afterChoice3() {
    setChips(true);
    setDrinks(true);
    setPrice(7);


    System.out.println("Meat Type? (Available types = A, B, C)");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char choice = scanner.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    switch (choice) {
        case 'A':
            setMeatType('A');
            break;
        case 'B':
            setMeatType('B');
            break;
        case 'C':
            setMeatType('C');
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("You have selected " + getMeatType() + " type of meat.\n*********");

    System.out.println("Bread Roll Type? (Available types = A, B, C)");
    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    char choice2 = scanner2.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    switch (choice2) {
        case 'A':
            setBreadRollType('A');
            break;
        case 'B':
            setBreadRollType('B');
            break;
        case 'C':
            setBreadRollType('C');
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("You have selected " + getBreadRollType() + " type of bread roll.\n*********");

    System.out.println("Tomatoes?\n1)Yes 2)No");
    Scanner scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice3 = scanner3.nextInt();

    switch (choice3) {
        case 1:
            setTomato(true);
            System.out.println("You have chosen to have tomatoes in your burger.\n*********");
            increasePrice(0.5);
            break;
        case 2:
            setTomato(false);
            System.out.println("You have chosen not to have tomatoes in your burger. \n*********");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Current price is " + getPrice() + " $\n*********");


    System.out.println("Lettuce?\n1)Yes 2)No");
    Scanner scanner4 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice4 = scanner4.nextInt();

    switch (choice4) {
        case 1:
            setLettuce(true);
            System.out.println("You have chosen to have lettuce in your burger.\n*********");
            increasePrice(1);
            break;
        case 2:
            setLettuce(false);
            System.out.println("You have chosen not to have lettuce in your burger. \n*********");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Current price is " + getPrice() + " $\n*********");


    System.out.println("Carrots?\n1)Yes 2)No");
    Scanner scanner5 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice5 = scanner5.nextInt();

    switch (choice5) {
        case 1:
            setCarrot(true);
            System.out.println("You have chosen to have carrots in your burger.\n*********");
            increasePrice(0.5);
            break;
        case 2:
            setCarrot(false);
            System.out.println("You have chosen not to have carrots in your burger. \n*********");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Current price is " + getPrice() + " $\n*********");


    System.out.println("Ketchup?\n1)Yes 2)No");
    Scanner scanner6 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice6 = scanner6.nextInt();

    switch (choice6) {
        case 1:
            setKetchup(true);
            System.out.println("You have chosen to have ketchup in your burger.\n*********");
            increasePrice(1);
            break;
        case 2:
            setKetchup(false);
            System.out.println("You have chosen not to have ketchup in your burger. \n*********");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Your order is sent.");
    System.out.println("Total price is " + getPrice() + " $\n*********");

}

public void setChips(boolean chips) {
    this.chips = chips;
}

public void setDrinks(boolean drinks) {
    this.drinks = drinks;
}

public boolean isChips() {
    return chips;
}

public boolean isDrinks() {
    return drinks;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`afterChoiceX` isn't making use of polymorphism. Let's look at an example of how you can take advantage of polymorphism.

```
public class BasicBurger {
    public void afterChoice() {
        // Gather options from user
    }
}

public class SpecialBurger1 extends BasicBurger {
    public void afterChoice() {
        // Gather options from user
    }
}
```

Notice that in `SpecialBurger1`, we simply override the method `afterChoice`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char choice = // Input from user
        BasicBurger burger;
        switch (choice) {
        case 'A':
            burger = new BasicBurger();
            break;
        case 'B':
            burger = new SpecialBurger1();
            break;
        default:
            // Exit
            return;
        }

        // The next line will invoke the method on the
        // appropriate class. This is polymorphism.
        burger.afterChoice();
    }
}
```

Base on this idea, we can implement our `toString()` in `BasicBurger` so that it encodes itself as a string.

```
public class BasicBurger {
    public void afterChoice() {
        // Gather options from user
    }

    public String toString() {
        String message = "'" + getMeatType() + "' meat, '"
            + getBreadType() + "' bread";

        if (lettuce) {
            message += ", lettuce";
        }

        if (carrot) {
            message += ", carrot",
        }

        // Do this for other possible ingredients of BasicBurger
        return message;
    }
}

public class SpecialBurger1 extends BasicBurger {
    public void afterChoice() {
        // Gather options from user
    }

    public String toString() {
        // The "super" keyword invokes the method "print"
        // of the closest parent that implements it.
        // In our case, BasicBurger#print() will be invoked.
        String message = super.toString();

        if (pickles) {
            message += ", pickles";
        }

        // Do this for other possible ingredients of SpecialBurger1
        return message;
    }
}
```

By adding the following line after `burger.afterChoice()`, a burger's information will be printed to your screen.

```
System.out.println("Your burger that consists of " + burger
    + " is ready to order.");
```

I hope this answer helped you understand more about polymorphism and inheritance.

Note: I typed this during my lunch break and didn't test it.

Comment: Very insightful. Thanks a lot for clarifying the use of polymorphism and also solving thr problem.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of McClane:

When doing OOP we identify objects with *same bahavior* where we build objects for. It does not nessessarily mean that we have to use *inheritance*

In you Program I see 4 Objects with unique behavior:

1. The "servant" asking the client which burger she wants
2. The Burger having a name, base price, a list of flexible parts and a list of fix parts. It can calculate its price and print its current state.
3. the BurgerPart that has some options and knows what was selected
4. the BurgerPartOption with a name and a price.

here is how I would implement that:

```
class BurgerPartChoice {
    public static final BurgerPartChoice NONE = new BurgerPartChoice("nothing", 0.0);
    public final String name;
    public final double price;

    public BurgerPartChoice(String name, double price) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

---

```
class BurgerPart {
    public final String name;
    private final BurgerPartChoice[] choices;
    private BurgerPartChoice choosen = BurgerPartChoice.NONE;

    public BurgerPart(String name, BurgerPartChoice... choices) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.choices = choices;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name
                + " "
                + choosen.name;
    }

    double getPrice() {
        return choosen.price;
    }

    void select(Scanner input) {
        int selection = choices.length; // invalid value
        while (true) {// infinite loop
            System.out.println("Coose a "
                    + name
                    + ", available options:");
            for (int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%s - %s", i, choices[i].name));
            }
            selection = input.nextInt();
            if (0 <= selection
                    && selection < choices.length) {
                choosen = choices[selection];
                return; // leave loop
            } else {
                System.err.println("invalid secletion!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class Burger {
    public final String name;
    private final BurgerPart[] burgerParts;
    private final double basePrice;
    private final List<BurgerPartChoice> fixParts;

    public Burger(String name, double basePrice, List<BurgerPartChoice> fixParts, BurgerPart... burgerParts) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.basePrice = basePrice;
        this.fixParts = fixParts;
        this.burgerParts = burgerParts;
    }

    double getPrice() {
        double price = basePrice;
        for (BurgerPartChoice burgerPartChoice : fixParts) {
            price += burgerPartChoice.price;
        }
        for (BurgerPart burgerPart : burgerParts) {
            price += burgerPart.getPrice();
        }
        return price;
    }

    void select(Scanner input) {
        for (BurgerPart burgerPart : burgerParts) {
            burgerPart.select(input);
            System.out.println(String.format("current price is: $%s", getPrice()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder idString = new StringBuilder(name);
        idString.append(" with ");
        String partSeparator = "";
        for (BurgerPart burgerPart : burgerParts) {
            idString.append(partSeparator);
            idString.append(burgerPart.toString());
            partSeparator = " and ";
        }
        idString.append(" for $");
        idString.append(getPrice());
        return idString.toString();
    }

}
```

---

```
public class BurgerShop {
    private static final List<BurgerPartChoice> NO_FIX_PARTS = Collections.emptyList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        BurgerPartChoice bredRollB = new BurgerPartChoice("B", 1.0);
        BurgerPartChoice bredRollC = new BurgerPartChoice("C", 1.5);
        BurgerPartChoice meatB = new BurgerPartChoice("B", 5.5);

        BurgerPart breadRoll = new BurgerPart("bread roll", new BurgerPartChoice("A", 0.0), bredRollB, bredRollC);
        BurgerPart meat = new BurgerPart("Meat", new BurgerPartChoice("A", 4.0), meatB, new BurgerPartChoice("C", 7.0));
        BurgerPart tomato = new BurgerPart("Tomato", new BurgerPartChoice("A", 0.25), new BurgerPartChoice("B", 0.75));
        BurgerPart mixedPickles = new BurgerPart("mixed pickles", new BurgerPartChoice("A", 0.25), new BurgerPartChoice("B", 0.5), new BurgerPartChoice("C", 0.75));
        BurgerPart chips = new BurgerPart("chips", new BurgerPartChoice("A", 0.25), new BurgerPartChoice("B", 0.5), new BurgerPartChoice("C", 0.5), new BurgerPartChoice("D", 1.75));
        BurgerPart drink = new BurgerPart("soft drink", new BurgerPartChoice("A", 0.25), new BurgerPartChoice("B", 0.5), new BurgerPartChoice("C", 0.75));

        Burger burger = new Burger("not choosen", 0.0, NO_FIX_PARTS);
        System.out.println("What type of burger do you want? \n1)Basic\n2)Special 1 (Healthy) \n3)Special 2 (Deluxe)");
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                burger = new Burger("basic Burger", 3.0, NO_FIX_PARTS, breadRoll, meat, tomato);
                break;
            case 2:
                List<BurgerPartChoice> specialBurgerFixParts = Arrays.asList(bredRollB);
                burger = new Burger("special Burger 1", 4.5, specialBurgerFixParts, meat, tomato, mixedPickles);
                break;
            case 3:
                List<BurgerPartChoice> burgermenuFixParts = Arrays.asList(bredRollC, meatB);
                burger = new Burger("special Burger 2", 5.25, burgermenuFixParts, tomato, mixedPickles, chips, drink);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Wrong Input");
                break;
        }
        burger.select(scanner);
        System.out.println(String.format("\n\nyour burger is %s", burger.toString()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         System.out.println("What type of burger do you want? \n1)Basic\n2)Special 1 (Healthy) \n3)Special 2 (Deluxe)");
>         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
>         int choice = scanner.nextInt();
>
>         switch (choice) {
>             case 1:
>                 BasicBurger basicBurger = new BasicBurger();
>                 basicBurger.afterChoice();
>                 break;
>             case 2:
>                 SpecialBurger1 specialBurger1 = new SpecialBurger1();
>                 specialBurger1.afterChoice2();
>                 break;
>             case 3:
>                 SpecialBurger2 specialBurger2 = new SpecialBurger2();
>                 specialBurger2.afterChoice3();
>                 break;
>             default:
>                 System.out.println("Wrong Input");
>                 break;
>         }
>     }
> ```

My IDE gives me a warning on code like this.  It doesn't like that the `Scanner` isn't closed.  I'm not convinced that this is a big deal with a `Scanner`, but it's easy enough to fix.

One option is to simply

```
    public static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner();
```

Then it will survive the length of the program, so it doesn't trigger the warning.

More extremely, you can use the `try`-with-resources form so that the `Scanner` will get closed automatically.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            Burger burger = chooseBurger(scanner);

            if (burger != null) {
                burger.customize();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Burger chooseBurger(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println("What type of burger do you want? "
            + "1)Basic\n2)Special 1 (Healthy) \n3)Special 2 (Deluxe)");

        switch (scanner.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
                return new BasicBurger();
            case 2:
                return new HealthyBurger();
            case 3:
                return new DeluxeBurger();
            default:
                System.out.println("Wrong Input");
        }

        return null;
    }

public interface Burger {

    public void customize(Scanner scanner);

}
```

I also find it easier to follow what the code in `chooseBurger` does now, as it is isolated from the rest of `main`.

I would prefer names without numbers, like `HealthyBurger` and `DeluxeBurger`.

We can call `customize` just once, where you had to call `afterChoice` three times under three different names.

I would prefer to create one `Scanner` and either access it from a common place or pass it to the methods and classes that need it.  This pattern is called [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

This way you can get rid of all the numbered `Scanner` objects.  Sometimes, you may have to do a `scanner.next()` after doing a `scanner.nextInt()` or whatever.  Because the `nextInt` can leave the new line on the input.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I also realized how poor names I have used thanks to you. Much appreciated

Comment: It is weird that I had no problems running in IntelliJ though